# how to save hidden field rails with javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have this dragabble canvas in my code.

See it run here: http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/190/

```
input_text:string
input_text_position:string
```

I want to save the position of the text, so I tried a `= f.hidden_field :input_text_position`

How do I save the position with JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set a handler on the "drag" event, setting the value of the hidden field at every event fire:

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Text(drag me)</p>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="position" id="position" />
```

Javascript:

```
$('#canvas').draggable().on('drag', function(e) {
    var offset = $('#canvas').offset();
    $('#position').val('(' + offset.left + ',' + offset.top + ')');
});
```

This sets the hidden field to a point like "(204,93)", which you can store in your database.